# Select the vector with largest minimum entries

Tags: matlab, sorting, compare

I generate `L` number of random vectors. I want to select the vector that has the largest minimum values, i.e., maximize the minimum (max-min).

I may implement this as:

1. sort entries of each vector in increasing order.
2. compare entries of the 1st smallest and select corresponding vectors which have maximum smallest values. If there are more than one vectors, I compare the second smallest entry of those. Still I have more than one vectors that have same 2nd smallest, I then compare 3rd and so on until I get single vector.

For example, I started to generate vectors as follows, but I do not know how to proceed to get above conditions.

```
K=1;N =9;L=4;
mat=zeros(K,N,L); sortmat=zeros(K,N,L);
for j=1:L
    mat(:,:,j)=randperm(15,N);
    sortmat(:,:,j)=sort(mat(:,:,j));
end
mat
sortmat
```

In one case, I got:

```
mat(:,:,1) =
     1    12    15    14     9     6     2    10     5
mat(:,:,2) =
     7    12     5     9    15     4    11     1    10
mat(:,:,3) =
     7    14     2     3    11     5    13     6    10
mat(:,:,4) =
    12     3    13     5    11     9    14     2    10

sortmat(:,:,1) =
     1     2     5     6     9    10    12    14    15
sortmat(:,:,2) =
     1     4     5     7     9    10    11    12    15
sortmat(:,:,3) =
     2     3     5     6     7    10    11    13    14
sortmat(:,:,4) =
     2     3     5     9    10    11    12    13    14
```

As this example, I should select the `mat(:,:,4)` vector. Because:

`mat(:,:,3)` and `mat(:,:,4)` have the largest of the 1st smallest value (which is 2) than `mat(:,:,1)` and `mat(:,:,2)` (they have 1). So I can ignore `mat(:,:,1)` and `mat(:,:,2)`.

Then, I compare the 2nd smallest of `mat(:,:,3)` and `mat(:,:,4)` - both have 3, so I cant select any. Then, compare 3rd smallest, still the same. Now I compare the 4th smallest where I found `mat(:,:,4)` has larger value which is 9 larger than 6.

Can someone help me to get this solution in MATLAB?

Comment: Looks like you've found a good algorithm. What is the difficulty in implementing it? The next step would be to use the [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function: `sortmat(:,:,1)==max(sortmat(:,:,1))` returns the indices of the vectors with the largest 1st element. But I would first reshape the matrices to be 2D, of size `K*N`x`L`, just in case one day you set `K` to be something other than 1.

Comment: I didnt understand how I use `sortmat(:,:,1)==max(sortmat(:,:,1))` to get the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you, should work with less dimensions matrix and use logical matrices.
So let's start

I will also changes de variables, First get the `N` vectors of length `L`:

```
>> N = 5;
>> L = 10;
```

Let's create a matrix N * L, that will contain the vectors

```
>> rand_matrix = randi([0,25],N,L)

rand_matrix =

    12    20    12    19     4    14    16     3    20    21
    11    12     3     6     7    11    24    15     9     6
    11     0     8    23     2    16     5    11    17    15
    20     4    15     6    14    16    18    11    10    15
     8    18     4    19    17    17     6    17    21    14
```

And begin with your algorithm, using matlab functions, sorting each row of the matrix:

```
>> sort_rand_matrix = sort(rand_matrix,2)

sort_rand_matrix =

     3     4    12    12    14    16    19    20    20    21
     3     6     6     7     9    11    11    12    15    24
     0     2     5     8    11    11    15    16    17    23
     4     6    10    11    14    15    15    16    18    20
     4     6     8    14    17    17    17    18    19    21
```

So now we have `N=5` sorted vectors of Length `L=10`, now let's start using logical matrix, first we want only maximum values of the first column:

```
>> TF1 = sort_rand_matrix(:,1) == max(sort_rand_matrix(:,1))

TF1 =

  5×1 logical array

   0
   0
   0
   1
   1

>> sort_rand_matrix(not(TF1),:) = []

sort_rand_matrix =

     4     6    10    11    14    15    15    16    18    20
     4     6     8    14    17    17    17    18    19    21

>> TF2 = sort_rand_matrix(:,2) == max(sort_rand_matrix(:,2))

TF2 =

  2×1 logical array

   1
   1

>> sort_rand_matrix(not(TF2),:) = []

sort_rand_matrix =

     4     6    10    11    14    15    15    16    18    20
     4     6     8    14    17    17    17    18    19    21

>> TF3 = sort_rand_matrix(:,3) == max(sort_rand_matrix(:,3))

TF3 =

  2×1 logical array

   1
   0

>> sort_rand_matrix(not(TF3),:) = []

sort_rand_matrix =

     4     6    10    11    14    15    15    16    18    20
```

You can see that on each iteration, we remove the rows that doesn't match the condition

Finally we can try to automate this. Note that it is important to delete the not valid rows in each step, because the maximum can be in a wrong row and also note that you can stop the `for` loop when you have only one element, let's work through each iteration:

```
for i = 1:L
  TF = sort_rand_matrix(:,i) == max(sort_rand_matrix(:,i))
  if length(TF) == 1
    break
  end
  sort_rand_matrix(not(TF(:,i)),:) = []
end
```

Let's try a complete a big one sample:

```
>> rand_matrix = randi([0,25],N,L)

rand_matrix =

    16     5     8    15     2    25     0     2     0     4     1    17     4     7    24     7     0    16     6    23
     9     7    24     6     6    14    23    16    19     6    17    13    10    11    23    18    14     9     7    22
    21    12    11    15    20    13    23    12    13    23     1    25    21     0     1    17    22     4    16    21
    13     5     4    18     0     6    20    20    12     0     1    16    20    25    19    14    17    11     6     6
     9    21    23     5    24    12     2    18    23    12    13    20     1     4     6    18     4    12    21    15
    24     5    25     3    18    16     6    23    15     4     2    11    10     2    10    17     9     3    25     0
    22     5    11     7    12    17     8    23    16    25    21    11    13     9    14     4    11    15    18    11
    14     4     2     8    15    10    17     8    22    18    21    21    10     5    24     3    25     5     8     8
    16     5     6    11     6     9     3    18    20    13    18     2    17    12    10    25     4    10    15     4
    15    11    10    13    11    25    18     5    14    12     3     3    16     8    25     4    22    15     2     4

>> sort_rand_matrix = sort(rand_matrix,2)

sort_rand_matrix =

     0     0     0     1     2     2     4     4     5     6     7     7     8    15    16    16    17    23    24    25
     6     6     6     7     7     9     9    10    11    13    14    14    16    17    18    19    22    23    23    24
     0     1     1     4    11    12    12    13    13    15    16    17    20    21    21    21    22    23    23    25
     0     0     1     4     5     6     6     6    11    12    13    14    16    17    18    19    20    20    20    25
     1     2     4     4     5     6     9    12    12    12    13    15    18    18    20    21    21    23    23    24
     0     2     2     3     3     4     5     6     9    10    10    11    15    16    17    18    23    24    25    25
     4     5     7     8     9    11    11    11    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    21    22    23    25
     2     3     4     5     5     8     8     8     8    10    10    14    15    17    18    21    21    22    24    25
     2     3     4     4     5     6     6     9    10    10    11    12    13    15    16    17    18    18    20    25
     2     3     3     4     4     5     8    10    11    11    12    13    14    15    15    16    18    22    25    25

>> for i = 1:L
  TF = sort_rand_matrix(:,i) == max(sort_rand_matrix(:,i));
  if length(TF) == 1
    break
  end
  sort_rand_matrix(not(TF),:) = [];
end
>> sort_rand_matrix

sort_rand_matrix =

     6     6     6     7     7     9     9    10    11    13    14    14    16    17    18    19    22    23    23    24
```

Comment: probably, `i` in `not(TF(:,i))` is `1` now.